# TSQL - Easiest way to set increasing value on the Position column ..order by Price

Tags: t-sql

Imagine a table with [ID, Name, Position, Price]

Currently the table has **ALL the records with Position=0** and **each record has a different price value**.

What is the quickest way **to update that Position** and set its value unique and based on the Price, where the record with the lowest price is Position=1, the second lowest is Position=2 ...and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `row_number` to number rows.  A subquery is required to refer to the row number by alias:

```
update  yt
set    Position = rn
from   (
       select  row_number() over (order by Price desc) as rn
       ,      *
       from    YourTable
       ) yt
```

[Working example at SE Data.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/120944/)